# How can automate updating jenkins plugins in docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have shell script for updating Jenkins plugins. I want to run the script inside docker container (where running Jenkins) to run the script always when start jenkins cointainer. When I run the script manualy inside container it works fine, but how to achieve run the script aumaticaly when Jenkins inside the cointainer is up.

Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean
user root
COPY jenkins_update.sh /opt/
```

jenkins_update.sh

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar --output /opt/jenkins-cli.jar

#waiting when jenkins will be up for download
#while true; do
#   sleep 10
#   curl --fail http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar --output /opt/jenkins-cli.jar && break
# done


UPDATE_LIST=$(java -jar /opt/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth "admin:admin" -noKeyAuth list-plugins | grep -e ')$' | awk '{ print $1 }' );
if [ ! -z "${UPDATE_LIST}" ]; then
echo Updating Jenkins Plugins: ${UPDATE_LIST};
java -jar /opt/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth "admin:admin" -noKeyAuth install-plugin ${UPDATE_LIST};
java -jar /opt/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth "admin:admin" -noKeyAuth safe-restart;
fi
```

docker-compose.yml

```
my_jenkins:
    build:
      context: jenkins_config/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    container_name: jenkins

    deploy:
          replicas: 1      
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure

    environment:
          - "JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

        command: ["/opt/jenkins_update.sh"]
```

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile /opt/jenkins-cli.jar

Comment: the script is falling due to that

Comment: a way it can be using crontab to schedule a job, but you should add into Dockerfile "USER root" and "RUN apk add --update busybox-suid" to grant the option to setup the cronjob into that alpine image (jenkinsci/blueocean). another way it add a script into Dockerfile something like "$ pgrep -f jenkins | wc -l" and use that as conditional to call the updating-script. btw the script needs the user:passwd access so I guess that's done when you finished to install the Jenkins setup?

Comment: I do not want use crontab. Id like have solution inside Dockerfile. First of all Im not able download jenkins-cli.jar, becouse in that time is Jenkins not fully running.When I created some loop inside jenkins_update.sh for waiting, inside container nothing happend until the loop(jenkins_update.sh) is finished so thats its not the way. Any other idea?